# What is the difference difference between a commercial vs. residential HVAC Condensor

Tags: hvac

Given a CARRIER  Central Air Conditioner **Commercial** Condenser 25HCE436A6:

[image]

How is this different from a similar HVAC condensor found for a residence?

Comment: Would think a commercial would be built better for harder use, but some companies might just add commercial to increase the mark up.  If given, then you should know to not look a horse in the mouth.

Comment: here is a nice article : https://www.servicechampions.net/blog/7-major-differences-residential-commercial-hvac-systems

Comment: @Ruskes Sorry, but that article is full of buzzwords and meaningless (some parts outright *wrong*) junk. About all it actually says is "commercial systems are bigger and more complicated, so they cost more". In other words, typical marketing page for an HVAC company.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact it is published by a reputable company

Comment: @Ruskes I will trust that the company listed on the web site is legitimate and can properly install/service HVAC equipment. But the content of the page is typical drivel.

Comment: The one you are showing does not qualifies as commercial. As rule of thumb if the HVAC is bigger than 5 Ton it enters the commercial size category.

Comment: There are many large, reputable companies that still put out standard, meaningless marketing drivel.

Answer (score 6):

Per the nameplate that I located on an eBay listing for that model, it runs on 460 volt three phase power. Very few residences are served by 460v three phase power. I would even say the odds of a single family house having that power available are very close to zero.

Comment: well done, this is the answer.

Comment: Given how few hits there are for this exact model number, I suspect it's the same listing that the OP looked at before asking the question.